# Can we hook a static method of a class to add_action inside that class?

Tags: plugins, hooks

So basically, what I'm trying to do is to hook a static method of a class to another static method of that same class.

Code is here :

```
class LocatorMap {
    
    public static function init() {

        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( __CLASS__, 'register_scripts' ) );

    }

    /* add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', array( 'LocatorMap', 'register_scripts' ) ); */
    public function register_scripts() {

        global $post;

        /* http or https */
        $scheme = parse_url( get_bloginfo('url'), PHP_URL_SCHEME );

        /* register gmaps api and info box */
        wp_register_script( 'google-maps-api', $scheme . '://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js', array('jquery'), FALSE, true );
        wp_register_script( 'google-maps-info-box', $scheme . '://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/infobox/1.1.13/src/infobox.js', array( 'jquery', 'google-maps-api' ), '1.1.13', true ); 

    }
}
```

Is this possible? I don't know since I'm a bit new on this kind of a structure.

**UPDATE**
I am also calling this class on an external file.

```
define( DEALERSHIP_MAP_URL, untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) )  );
define( DEALERSHIP_MAP_DIR, untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) );
define( DEALERSHIP_MAP_TEMPLATE, DEALERSHIP_MAP_DIR . '/templates' );

require_once( 'core/class-locator-map.php' );

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'LocatorMap', 'init' ) );
```

Comment: yes it's possible and you did it right, did you get any error?

Comment: Hi @GovindKumar was not getting any error, however the scripts are not enqueued when I view the source of the page. 

I did use wp_enqueue_script function I just forgot to include it on my example. sorry.

that class LocatorMap is being hooked to the register_activation_hook function as 

include_once( 'inc/class-locator-map.php' );

`register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'LocatorMap', 'init' ) );`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`register_activation_hook`  only runs once i.e. when the plugin is first activated - use the `init` hook instead to "boot up" your plugin:

```
add_action( 'init', 'LocatorMap::init' );
```

Comment: ahh yeah, I only need to register the scripts once. so I kinda use that `register_activation_hook` can I use the `add_action( 'init', array( 'LocatorMap', 'init' ) );` ? but `init` maybe do it too. I think?

Answer (score 6):

I recently had to do the same thing and ended up using the [`static::` late static binding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php#language.oop5.late-static-bindings.usage) along with [special `::class` constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php#example-188). The `static::` binding will reference the calling class, while the `::class` constant will return a string that is the name of the calling class (with namespacing!)

Using the example from the questiom, the implementation would like something like this:

```php
class LocatorMap {
    
    public static function init() {
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( static::class, 'registerScripts' ) );
    }

    public function registerScripts() {}
}
```

Since `static::` references the calling class, this allows to write reusable classes for your plugins/themes, and kind of wrap up some of WordPress' legacy ugliness.

For example, you could write an abstract class for custom post types like this:

```
namespace WordpressPlugin;

abstract class AbstractPostType {
  const SLUG;

  private function __construct() {}

  public static function initialize() {
    add_action( 'init', array( static::class, 'registerPostType' ), 0 );
    add_action( 'init', array( static::class, 'registerTaxonomies' ), 1 );
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( static::class, 'addMetaBox' ) );
  }

  public static function registerPostType() {}

  public static function registerTaxonomies() {}

  public static function addMetaBox() {}
}
```

Aftet that, you can now create custom post types without having to duplicate all of the boilerplate in each subclass, like this:

```php
namespace WordpressPlugin;

class ExamplePostType extends AbstractPostType {
  const SLUG = 'example-post-type';

  public static function registerPostType() {
    register_post_type( self::SLUG, array(
      ...
    ) );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the neat example

Answer (score 4):

use the function `get_called_class()`

```
public static function init() {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( get_called_class(), 'register_scripts' ) );
}
```